# How to use Visual Studio and CMAKE and GTEST to generate code coverage report

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, googletest

I'm trying to generate a code coverage report using visual studio 2022, using cmake + gtest, but my vs2022 always doesn't work. I've rummaged through google and microsoft documentation and couldn't find a solution.

If I open the project with the .sln file generated by cmake , the code coverage report is generated fine.

That is, when I open a typical vs project (.sln) I can generate the report, but the cmake project does not.

The following three files are the configuration I use, one of the simplest cmake + gtest configuration, the third file is to configure the `generator` of vs to `Visual Studio 17 2022` (to get the .sln file).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)

project(cmake-example-test)

set(
  TEST_SOURCES
  "test.cpp"
)

# gtest
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  # URL https://file.winterwonder.top/public/package/googletest-release-1.11.0.zip
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${TEST_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

```cpp
// test.cpp

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(hello, world) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

// CMakeSettings.json

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can't find the same question online, is it rare that anyone needs a code coverage report? Or neither use visual studio? I use lcov on linux, but obviously Visual Studio on windows is more convenient and powerful.

Comment: Maybe it can't? CMake support in MSVS is limited, solutions have much better support.

Comment: Well, it should be like this.